# Is there any non-complete metric on $\Bbb R^2$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I've read several books with this content:

> Let $g = dr^2 + f^2(r)d\theta^2$ be a smooth metric on $\Bbb R^2$ expressed in
>   polar coordinates. This metric is **complete** and the **volume can be finite** even though this manifold is not-compact.

I thought that $\Bbb R^2$ always have infinite volume.

> **Question:** Why authors emphasize that this metric is complete while we know that $\Bbb R^2$ is complete topological space. Is there any non-complete metric on $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: Does the author mean Cauchy complete or geodesic complete?

Comment: is there difference between them? I think geo. complete.

Comment: Completeness is not a property of topological spaces so I don't know what you mean by "$\mathbb{R}^2$ is complete topological space."

Comment: @edm According to Hopf–Rinow, those are equivalent.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, Thank you for your remark.

Comment: Such metric can't be induced by a norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exists a diffeomorphism from $\Bbb R^2$ to the open unit disc. One such function, given in polar form, is $(r,\theta)\mapsto(\tanh r,\theta)$. You can replace $\tanh$ with your favorite [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function). Give the open unit disc the standard metric, and then give $\Bbb R^2$ the metric it inherits from the diffeomorphism. This metric is not complete.

This doesn't contradict the author's statement, because metrics of the form $dr^2+f^2(r )d\theta^2$ do not change the lengths of rays from the origin, and so the metric I described above is not of this form.